# Pass EmailTemplate relatedTo wholesale to a Visualforce Component?

Tags: visualforce, email, visualforce-component, email-template

Let's say I have a `Visualforce Component` similar to below:

```
<apex:component access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="relatedTo" type="MyObject__c" />
</apex:component>
```

Now if I have an `EmailTemplate` where I want to pass this record in, I expected the following to work:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="..." 
                         recipientType="User" 
                         replyTo="..."
                         relatedToType="MyObject__c"
                         language="{!recipient.LanguageLocaleKey}">
    <c:myComponent relatedTo="{!relatedTo}" />
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

However, when I try to save the template, I get this error:

> Error: Unknown property 'MyObject__cStandardController.relatedTo'

The merge fields which reference specific fields on the record work just fine. For example, this type of reference will save:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!relatedTo.SomeField__c}" />
```

Is it not possible to pass the entire `relatedTo` record? Do I have to pss the `Id` and re-query all the fields I need manually?

Comment: Were you able to save visual component? I was not able to save without the description field probably that's the root cause of your issue?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I just didn't include it in the markup here. Yes the component saved.

Comment: Turns out the problem seems to occur only when you name the attribute `relatedTo`. When I renamed it to `record`, it worked just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be answer but I was able to save this.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="QEE" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Account">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
Congratulations!
This is your new Visualforce Email Template.
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>

<c:MycustomComponent record="{!relatedTo}"/>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

You sure you don't have any other issue?